# Detect battery/cell's charge

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, indicator, portable

I am building a portable device with Raspberry Pi and powered by 3 **AAA batteries** in series. I am trying to create a battery indicator with a **LED**:

- **Green = Full power**
- **Orange = Half power**
- **Red = Low power**

This is not an indicator for charging the battery, since I am not doing that. The purpose of this is to let me know when I have to change the batteries.The Raspberry Pi has an **ADC** that I can use. The device works from 6V to 3.3V (3xAAA cells that I usually use gives me 3.6V, but depending on the cells I get 4.5V).

Is there a simple way for me to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Add more information about your device. Does it have a micro-controller with an analog input that could be used to measure the voltage? How many batteries? i.e., What voltage range? Have you decided the _voltages_ that you want the LEDs to switch at? Add all this information **into your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: I edited the question adding info.

Comment: 3 cells is pretty low for 3.3V. Starting out at 1.25V, NIMHs will quickly drop to 1.1V under load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQNAp2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Potential divider for ADC. (b) Calibration circuit.*

You only need a potential divider such as Figure 1a to bring the battery voltage down into the range of the ADC. Just make sure that at maximum voltage that you don't exceed the ADC input voltage.

You can calibrate and test as shown in Figure 1b.